# Cant read attribute in jQuery (gets undefined)

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-6

My HTML code:

```
<td>
    <select name="fieldType" class="form-control show-dropdown-modals">
        <option>Text Input</option>
        <option value="codes-dropdown" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#codesDropdownModal" for="codesDD" for-display="codesDDDisplay">Codes Dropdown</option>
        <option>Date</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="codesDDDisplay" id="codesDDDisplay" value="" class="form-control hidden" readonly="readonly"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="codesDD" id="codesDD" value="" />
</td>
```

This select opens a modal with this code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="codesDropdownModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="codesDropdownModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Select Codes</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <select class="form-control codes-table">
                            <option value="AGENCY">Agency</option>
                            <option value="OFFICE">Office</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Option</label>
                        <select class="form-control codes-column">
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary add-codes" href="#">Ok</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery Code (ES6)

```
registerPageEvents() {
    $('#codesDropdownModal').on('show.bs.modal', (event) => {
        const targetInput = $(event.relatedTarget).attr('for'); //this gets undefined
        const targetDisplay = $(event.relatedTarget).attr('for-display'); //this gets undefined
        this.registerCodesModalEvents(targetInput, targetDisplay);
    });
}
registerCodesModalEvents(targetInput, targetDisplay) {
    $('.add-codes').unbind();
    $('.add-codes').click(() => {
        this.saveCodesSelection(targetInput, targetDisplay);
        $('#codesDropdownModal').modal('hide');
    });
}

saveCodesSelection(targetInput, targetDisplay) {
    let displayTable = $('#codesDropdownModal').find('.codes-table').val();
    let displayColumn = $('#codesDropdownModal').find('.codes-column').val();
    let displayText = displayTable + '.' + displayColumn;
    let value = displayText;
    $('input[name="' + targetInput + '"]').val(value);
    $('input[name="' + targetDisplay + '"]').val(displayText);
}
```

At this point, the error I get is both targetInput and tagetDisplay undefined (please ignore that both will have the same value). Other than that, everything goes OK.

Comment: Are you sure `event.relatedTarget` is the element you expect it to be?

Comment: Doubt this will work cross browser. Events don't register on `<option>` in some browsers. Suggest you manually show modal in change event of the `<select>`

Comment: @Barmar Im using it because I read somewhere it is the way, but if you think it is not correct, please suggest me a work around for this code to work. Thanks!

Comment: @charlietfl please may you extend your solution?

Comment: @EduardoSánchez I don't know if it's correct or not, since I have no idea what you're trying to do. However, `for` is not a valid attribute in an `<option>` element. AFAIK, it's only used in `<label>`, to connect the label with its associated input.